# Show Grid Item According Screen Size in Android GridView

Tags: android, gridview

[image][image]

Hello, I would like to develop android app that have many categories to show.
And I would like to support multi-screen size. Now, I decide to show with gridview like the sample image.

Question 1:

Is this UI is suitable or not for this application? If this UI is not good for this app, please give me some advice. :)

Question  2:

Is it possible to implement it? Bcz I'm a newbie to Android. I have no idea how to show grid item count according to screen size. Please help.

Question 3:

I would like to learn and create app that support multi-screen size and responsive layout. Is there any good ref: source to learn?

Thank you.

Comment: mulipal device comfortable layout ...........

Comment: It is possible. I did it. But you will need to support different screensizes with different layouts

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

That worked well for [me](https://gist.github.com/sakurabird/6868765)

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: I think that is ok layout with some careful implementation. You can follow the material design guideline: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/grid-lists.html#grid-lists-behavior

One of the point in the guideline for responsive design:

> Responsive design
>
> Full-screen grid lists should use fluid image ratios with minimum and
>   maximum widths, derived using the Ratio keylines. They should retain
>   fixed heights, margins, and padding.
>
> Centered grid lists have fluid margins with a minimum width. They
>   maintain fixed image widths, heights, and padding.

Question 2: you can try the solution in this answer: [How to set Staggered grid layout in different screen dimensions.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988315/how-to-set-staggered-grid-layout-in-different-screen-dimensions)

Question 3: I find android site is a good source: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html